# How to detect the positive solution to this logistic boundary value problem

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics

I am trying to find the positive solution to this nonlinear ODE. Theoretically, it has been proven that this problem has a unique positive solution for lam large. But, Mathematica can detect only the zero solution (zero is a solution for all lam's). Any techniques to detect the positive solution?

```
lam = 30;
sol = NDSolve[{-D[f[x], x, x] == lam*f[x]*(1 - f[x]), 
(D[f[x], x] /. x -> 1) == -Sqrt[lam]*0.1*f[1], (*first boundary condition*) 
(D[f[x], x] /. x -> 0) == Sqrt[lam]*0.1*f[0]}, (*second boundary condition*) 
f, {x, 0, 1}];
```

```
Plot[f[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, f}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try a [shooting method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method). The following code produces the solution for a given value of `f[0]`:

```
lam = 30;
sol[f0_?NumericQ]:=NDSolveValue[{-f''[x]==lam*f[x]*(1-f[x]),
                                 f[0]==f0,f'[0]==Sqrt[lam]*0.1*f0},f,{x,0,1}];
```

We want to understand for which `f[0]` the boundary condition at `x==1` is satisfied. This condition is that the following must be zero:

```
cond1[f_]:=f'[1]-(-Sqrt[lam]*0.1*f[1])
```

Let us plot this:

```
Plot[cond1[sol[f0]],{f0,-0.53,0.91},AxesLabel->{"f[0]","cond1"}]
```

[image]

I picked the plot domain after some playing around. We see four values of `f[0]` where the condition at `x==1` is also satisfied. I think the one OP asks for is the one on the very right, so let us see where it is:

```
f0x=f0/.FindRoot[cond1[sol[f0]],{f0,0.9}]
(* 0.905557 *)
```

Plot the corresponding solution:

```
With[{s=sol[f0x]}, Plot[s[x],{x,0,1},AxesLabel->{"x","f[x]"}]]
```

[image]

It is everywhere positive. It is also not difficult to guess that this solution is symmetric, $f(x) = f(1-x)$, and a numerical check confirms this. No error or warning message was produced, so I am assuming we can trust the numerical evaluation. But of course, one should check.

**Note.** The above is a manual implementation of the shooting method. Actually `NDSolve` has a shooting method built in. To see how this works, see [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html). Here:

```
lam=30;
sol2[f0guess_?NumericQ]:=NDSolveValue[{
                     -f''[x]==lam*f[x]*(1-f[x]),
                     f'[0]==Sqrt[lam]*0.1*f[0],
                     f'[1]==-Sqrt[lam]*0.1*f[1]},
                     f,x,Method->{"Shooting","StartingInitialConditions"->
                          {f[0]==f0guess,f'[0]==Sqrt[lam]*0.1*f0guess}}];
```

Let us use this to plot the four solutions mentioned above:

```
With[{sols=Map[sol2[#][x]&,{-0.5,0,0.85,0.9}]},
  Plot[Evaluate[sols],{x,0,1},PlotStyle->{Black,Blue,Green,Magenta},AxesLabel->{"x","f[x]"}]]
```

[image]

**Note 2.** The quantity `1/2*f'[x]^2+lam*(1/2*f[x]^2-1/3*f[x]^3)` is independent of `x` for every solution.